# Compilation failure when using @Transactional(value = "primary")

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, transactional

In pom.xml I use spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, but maven compiles the project with an error:

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project transaction: Compilation failure
\p4_projects\transaction\src\main\java\com\sick\dao\hibernate\DeviceModelDaoHibernate.java:[25,15] cannot find symbol symbol  : method value() 
location: @interface org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

I cannot find the reason. Dependency Hierarchy shows correct version 4.1.4 for all spring dependencies. I have the same result with 4.1.3.

I'll appreciate your help. 
Thanks,
Elena

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sick.dao.DeviceModelDao;
import com.sick.model.DeviceModel;

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "primary")
public class DeviceModelDaoHibernate implements DeviceModelDao {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public DeviceModelDaoHibernate() {      
}

public DeviceModelDaoHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public void save(DeviceModel deviceModel) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(deviceModel);
}
```

}

pom.xml is too big to post here, therefore I publish only versions of dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <red5-server.version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</red5-server.version>
    <red5-client.version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</red5-client.version>
    <camel.version>2.14.1</camel.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-integration.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring-integration.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <mina.version>2.0.7</mina.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <cargo.host>localhost</cargo.host>
    <cargo.port>25888</cargo.port>
    <cargo.wait>false</cargo.wait>
    <tomcat.version>6.0.14</tomcat.version>
</properties>
....
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: please include the code for the class / interface where you're using `@Transactional` -- also, maybe show your `pom.xml` or `mvn tree`

Comment: Taking at look through the versions @ http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/2.5.3/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.java it seems that the `String value() default ""` definition on that annotation has been around since at least `3.0.0.RELEASE`, so your  error seems suspicious

Comment: POM.xml is too big to post here.

Comment: Can you post how you have declared the `spring-tx` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse?
Try Maven clean > Project clean > Maven install.
Error is suspicious indeed, I think you do not have problem with code but with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody, I have already resolved that issue. In pom.xml I've placed all org.springframework dependencies before org.hibernate dependencies and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here: the @Transactional was wrongly coming from an old "spring-dao" library, wich was a transitive dependency for "spring-hibernate3" but I wanted it from "spring-tx".

Solved it by moving the "spring-tx" dependency before the "spring-hibernate3" (I supposed I could have used exclusions too).

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to visualize transitive dependencies.